# find parent node of the child that contains text

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have got structure like this:

```
div
    div
       span **text NAME_OF_SOMETHINK**
    div
       span **text ADVERT**
div
   ...
      ...
div
   ...
      ...
```

I need to extract text >NAME_OF_SOMETHINK from span, if relative div have span that contains text > ADVERT

Comment: please provide html code.

Comment: Also show how you tried

Comment: I tried like this
        `for field in response.xpath("//div[@class = '_awwm2v']/div"):
            if 'ADVERT' in field.xpath("child::div/span[@class'_1k70kjvn']/text()").get():
                advert_providers = field.xpath("child::span[@class = '_hc69qa']/text()").get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
response.xpath(
    "//div[contains(., 'ADVERT')]/../preceding-sibling::div/span[contains(., 'NAME_OF_SOMETHINK')]/text()"
).getall()
```